# How to adding queuing to the reading and updating of variables?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, architecture, queue

Say I have a variable called meow. meow is equal to 25. Say I also have two functions running asynchronously. At some point both of these functions are going to need to access the value in the meow variable, and change it by adding 3 to it. Here's the problem though, if one of the asynchronous functions is doing this update process on meow, the other one should wait until it is done. In a sense a queue must be made to access/change the meow variable. How is this done most often in C++ according to the programming language meta?

Comment: "according programming language meta" - What is that?

Comment: sorry if that is unclear, im just asking what is the "goto" method to do this in C++ VS a more archaic solution should one exist.

Comment: Well, that's still not clear, but take a look at  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread

Comment: Look at `std::atomic`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two main choices: atomics and mutexes. If you are only incrementing one shared variable and you don't care which order the increments occur, you can use atomic variables.

See [the documentation for std::atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) for full information. The following shows how you would increment by three an atomic variable called `myatom`.

```
myatom.fetch_add(3);
```

Note that `fetch_add` returns the value **before the operation**, so if `myatom` were 0 before the call to `fetch_add`, the function would return 0 and `myatom` would be set to 3.

The `atomic<>` template also overloads the arithmetic operators, but I prefer to use the member functions to make it clearer that the operation is dealing with an atomic variable. Makes it easier to track down issues.